# print a table as a label in R

Tags: python, r, igraph

How can I print a table as a label in R,

An example:

```
 library(igraph)
 g4 <- graph( c("John", "Jim", "Jim", "Jack", "Jim", "Jack", "John", "John"),
         isolates=c("Jesse", "Janis", "Jennifer", "Justin") )
# In named graphs we can specify isolates by providing a list of their names.
plot(g4, edge.arrow.size=.5, vertex.color="gold", vertex.size=15,
 vertex.frame.color="gray", vertex.label.color="black",
 vertex.label.cex=0.8, vertex.label.dist=2, edge.curved=0.2,vertex.label=c("Table 1","Table 2","Table 
3","Table 4","Table 5","Table 6","Table 7"))
```

What I am getting:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]